# jwt claim on blazor web assembly and web api claim

Tags: jwt, blazor-webassembly, claims

when i generate jwt token on server, one of my claim is ClaimType.Name,
but in blazor web assembly when i parse jwt token and get claims,
it's name changed to unique_name.

can anyone explain why this is happen?

on server

```
new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Username);
```

on blazor web assembly

```
"unique_name" = "myUsername"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by design. [This post](https://forums.asp.net/post/6320822.aspx) has the details with excerpts from the JwtSecurityTokenHandler code.

The rule you found is from this Dictionary entry that is used to do a mapping:

```
{ JwtRegisteredClaimNames.UniqueName, ClaimTypes.Name },
```

Basically, Microsoft Identity Claims are converted (when appropriate) to JWT standard names.